# Use geometry binary predicate list to subset simple feature object?

Tags: gdal, r, overlapping-features, sp, rgdal

I am trying to create a new simple feature from two overlapping features. I want to subset all polygons that are fully or partially located within my buffer (red border).

[image]

However, the `st_overlaps` generates  `Sparse geometry binary predicate list`. I have honestly no idea **how to use this list to subset my original fc to create new geometry?**. This [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294933/r-convert-output-from-sfst-within-to-vector) using `st_within` does not work: `nbrs.buff <- left[st_overlaps(buff, left) %>% lengths  > 1, ]`, as it subset all of the files, not ones overed by `buffer`. What I am missing?

Here is my dummy example:

```
# Load data
shp = system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")

my.sf <- st_read(shp, quiet = TRUE)

# Convert crs to projected system to make buffer
my.sf.web<- st_transform(my.sf, 3857)

# Subset the data to create two independent shps
i = 10

# Split datasets in two files
one  = my.sf.web[i, ]
left = my.sf.web[-i,]

# Create buffer 
buff = st_buffer(one, 40000 ) # distance


# CHeck which polygons overlaps with my buffer
out.overlap = st_overlaps(buff, left)

# Subset the overlapping polygons to create new geometry: DOES NOT WORK??
nbrs.buff <- left[st_overlaps(buff, left) %>% lengths  > 1, ]
```

Comment: In st_overlaps you can set st_overlaps(buff,left, sparse = F) if you want an resulting sf object and not a sparse geometry list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buff` is only a single feature. Then `st_overlaps(buff, left)`  is a list with one element (the row numbers of the seven features it overlaps with).

Getting the first (and only) element of the list gets you the row numbers in `left` of the overlap. So subset that:

```
 left[st_overlaps(buff,left)[[1]],]
```

If you did the overlaps test the other way round then you get a longer list with an element for each feature in `left` which will be 0 for no overlaps. You can then test for any overlap to get the row index:

```
> which(lengths(st_overlaps(left,buff))>0)
[1]  3 11 22 25 38 39 41
```

which should be the same as:

```
> st_overlaps(buff,left)[[1]]
[1]  3 11 22 25 38 39 41
```

Comment: Wow @spacedman, this works!! However, can you explain why the wor numbers of `nbrs.buff <- left[st_overlaps(buff,left)[[1]],]` print out by  `as.numeric(rownames(nbrs.buff))` are  `[1]  3 12 23 26 39 40 42` and not  ` 3 11 22 25 38 39 41` in you example? I wonder why there is always `3` but other numbers are increased by one, which would be logical? Thanks again!

Comment: rownames are preserved on subsetting. The original data set has rownames "1" to "100". When you chop out `buff` at row 10 then `left` has 99 rownames: "1" to "9" then "11" to "100". So row 10 has rowname "11". Note I use quotes for rownames because they are character strings and not numbers.

Comment: Oh, I see. Perfectly logical, that I have first removed one item. Thank you again!